# Task 'sonarqube' not found in root project

Tags: java, gradle, sonarcloud

I am trying to add sonarqube to my project and I followed the steps and added those lines to my `build.gradle` file

```
plugins {
  id "org.sonarqube" version "3.3"
}

sonarqube {
  properties {
    property "sonar.projectKey", "myproject"
    property "sonar.organization", "myusername"
    property "sonar.host.url", "https://sonarcloud.io"
  }
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Task 'sonarqube' not found in root project  'myproject'
```

I am using Gradle 6.9

Comment: Try the fixes here:https://github.com/emAmazed/redlamp/issues/31#:~:text=Issue%3A%20Task%20%27sonarqube%27%20not%20found%20in%20root%20project.,that%20you%20should%20use%20to%20run%20this%20locally..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to specify the location of my `settings.gradle` file as it is not located in the same folder than my `build.gradle` file.

```
--settings-file=
```

Comment: Specify it where?

Comment: In the `build.yml` file, such as: `sonarqube --settings-file=./folder/settings.gradle`

Comment: I don't have build.yml file.......what should I do....please help.

Comment: @sam_urai What are you trying to do ? A `build.yml` file is specific to GitHub, can you give more details ?

Comment: @Frederic I am building the app in react native which have an android and ios project folder I am trying to add sonar qube in Android project and I don't have build.yml file